# Bifrost not updating events after ether sent to address warning error thrown

Tags: transactions, xlm, bifrost

```
h=00000000000002c4e16bb85581427717efbd418a3e954064b2b532e02672a568 blockTime=2018-04-11 20:10:28 +0000 UTC pid=2514 service=BitcoinListener transactions=1
WARN[2018-04-11T20:10:39Z] Error extracting addresses                    blockHash=00000000000002c4e16bb85581427717efbd418a3e954064b2b532e02672a568 blockTime=2018-04-11 20:10:28 +0000 UTC err="opcode OP_DATA_75 requires 76 bytes, but script only has 39 remaining" pid=2514 service=BitcoinListener transactionHash=7265fb8d8c723324839767fddacc3fb093c5291d4c244347eb5257cb5ed1e1ff transactions=1
INFO[2018-04-11T20:10:39Z] Processed block
```

We are getting this error now but where doing a eth transaction not bitcoin. I google the error. and came up with some stuff that didn't apply I think

https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/issues/962
https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/issues/649